# Altium 20 Deleting Rules

Tags: altium, drc

I have Altium 20.0.11.

My rules keep getting deleted when I update from the schematic. 
Any rule I set in the PCB gets removed when I perform an update from the schematic. 
This the only project I have that does this.

There must be some setting that I am missing.

I do have Altium support but there new system sucks and it can take days (been waiting a week to get a response to another issue) so I figure this is maybe faster.

Comment: Do you have "Ignore Rules Defined in PCB Only" checked under the "Comparator" tab in the Project --> Project Options dialog?

Comment: @DerStrom8 Done that not to long ago actually. Didn't change anything. I opened up a ticket with Altium but might take awhile before I get a response.

Comment: Rev back to Alitum 19 maybe?

Answer (score 1):

In Project Options / Comparator set "Extra Rules" to "Ignore Differences". See image below:

[image: screenshot of settings]